# Ubuntu 22.04 having reccuring deadlock freezes when working with a huge part of my RAM being in use (kernel 6.0.0 and 6.2.7)

Tags: 22.04, ram, deadlock

I am working on a Windows-Ubuntu dual boot laptop, mainly using Ubuntu 22.04 for my studies.

In the recent month I was working on a full stack Spring-Boot-Angular web application in IntelliJ and faced at least 5 times (once in a couple of days) a situation, which I can best describe as a "deadlock". My OS was totally frozen, not reacting to any actions, only holding the power button for 3 seconds helped to force a reboot.

The project is an important information, because the frontend & backend development servers as well as IntelliJ indexing the whole JAVA JDK and Sprint-Boot libraries (and loading them into the RAM, as far as I understand) usually take up almost all of my 8 GB RAM and normally the 4 GB SWAP partition is also in extensive use (I see values like 60 percent most of the time with this setup related to swap usage).

In these scenarios, all the sudden, the OS does react anymore.

I have been using Kernel 6.0.0. but after updating to 6.2.7, the behaviour stayed the same.

**Could someone please explain me: is this normal?
Might it be a bug in the kernel? Like that the deadlock detection does not cover all cases / is buggy?**

After managing to restart, I see Ubuntu logging out the orphaned i-nodes, which I think is quite normal, I just want to mention it, it might be of use.

Comment: You mention non-Ubuntu kernels?  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS uses 5.15 if using GA, 5.19 if using HWE & 6.2 for edge wasn't yet *deemed* ready last I checked..  Are you using Ubuntu?  If using *testing* kernels as it appears you are, they are intended for *testing* purposes, so why not report the problems you're having!  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: For a development machine to have just 8GB of RAM and 4GB of swap is suboptimal. A lot of modern development tools are resource hogs. For basic setups running your stack, it’s better to have at least 16GB of RAM and 20GB of swap. If this is not possible, then start by increasing your swap to 20GB and watching for performance hiccups. When problems appear, slowly increase the swap by a few GB. However, RAM is really the solution here 

Comment: Thank You all for Your answers! 
I do not use these Kernels for testing purposes. First of all, it was suggested by some automatic updating routine (Software Updater or so, maybe Mainline Kernel Installer), secondly, I used to face severe bugs which where promised to be corrected in kernel version 6, that's why I updated at first (one of them was actually an IntelliJ one, for which I got the instruction from their support team, to try a never kernel, and it worked).

I will try to increase the SWAP size, modify swappiness and edit my question with what @waltinator suggested tomorrow.

Comment: @waltinator I just jumped into your trap, sorry, I just did not read your whole comment, I admit my mistake.

I do not know what you expected me to add, I did not find anything helpful for the solution in the man pages.

As you see, I am pretty new to Linux and to this forum, you might try not to threaten me all the sudden with the consequences of my actions ;)

You also did not read everything, it seems, it stays there, that I have 4 GB swap space.

Can someone please explain, why using the add comment function would be illegal if I am the questioner?